# If $y=(3x+1)(3x+4)\cdots(3x+22)$ prove that $\Delta^4 y=136080(3x+13)(3x+16)(3x+19)(3x+22)$

Tags: numerical-methods

This is an assignment question from the topic 'Interpolation'
I tried to begin this sum by calculating
$\Delta^4=y_4-4y_3+6y_2-4y_1+y_0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with 
\begin{align}
(Δy)(x)&=y(x+1)-y(x)
\\
&=(3x+4)(3x+7)···(3x+22)·\bigl((3x+25)-(3x+1)\bigr)
\\
&=24·(3x+4)(3x+7)···(3x+22)
\end{align}

---

Continue with
$$
(Δy)(x+1)=24·(3x+7)(3x+10)···(3x+25)
$$

Comment: From where did (3x+25) come? And why (3x+1) is being subtracted from it?

Comment: $y(x+1)=(3x+4)···(3x+25)$ and extracting common factors from the difference $y(x+1)-y(x)$.